Adding function to entire column in Google Sheets
I made a Google sheet to track my progress in Street Fighter 6 I have a simple function in D2 of =c2-b2 that I want to apply to the whole column but adjust by row automatically, i.e. in D3 =c3-b2, etc. The best I can figure out is that I might need an array formula. Would anyone be able to help me with this?
I tried a few things I saw on older posts about using Crtl+Shift+Down+d but that just gives me the Chrome bookmark pop up. I saw some post about array formulas but that went swift over my head.


D2 =c2-b2
D3 =c3-b2

delete everything in D2:D range and use in D2:
=ARRAYFORMULA(C2:C-B2)

to hide those zeroes use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/(C2:C-B2)


thank you very much, I mistyped I wanted D3 to be c3-b3, d4 being c4-b4 etc, I thought I could figure it out myself but I keep getting errors, could I trouble you to tell me how that would be formatted?
Thank you for the above though I'm going to use it to keep overall track from my beginning starting point

@True_Tech use in D2: =ARRAYFORMULA(C2:C-B2:B)

I was able to use this as a starting point and made some progress! I gotta figure out the proper way to make no input not give any info but I've made real progress to keep this automated and share it with friends.
